# File Import on Chisel3.2

Tags: chisel

I would like to separate a single file having multiple classes, and to struct directories putting class by its category.
For example directory;

```
root-+-PE.scala
     |
     +-noc-+-InLink.scala
     |     |
     |     +-OutLink.scala
     |
     +-alu-+-Adder.scala
     |     |
     |     +-Multiplier.scala
     |
     +-util-+-PipelineRegister.scala
            |
            +-Token.scala
```

`InLink` and `OutLink` would like to reference Token.scala file.
I declare **package** in every file

To reference Token.scala,

- `import util._` in `InLink.scala` and `OutLink.scala` can not reference class in `Token.scala` file.

Can you guess where is my misunderstanding about the import?

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple files belonging to the same package and each of those files can have multiple classes. When that is the case you can directly use import package_name.class_name to import the particular class in a particular file. So if you want inLink and Outlink to reference a class in token.scala in each of those files just add `import package_name.class_name_inside_token.scala_that_you_want_to_reference`