# How to import packages into another package(or files in the same package) using "import" explicitly only once

Tags: scala, chisel

I'm using chisel based on scala with IntilliJ IDEA. The files in my project are in the same package named ***mypackage***, and I need to import the chisel's library:

// file1.scala
package mypackage
import chisel3._
import chisel3.util._
/** my code */

// file2.scala
package mypackage
import chisel3._
import chisel3.util._
/** my code */

...

I hope to automatically/implicitly add the two libraries above to all files in ***mypackage***, so that I don't need to repeat "import" in every file.

Thanks!

Comment: If you use **sbt** as your build tool there is a way to configure the default imports of all files... but I personally would recommend not doing that and just live with the imports.

Comment: Thanks your suggestion.@LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez.I think configure sbt is effective, and I wonder why not recommend doing that

Comment: Because newcomers may be confused why the code of that file works but in another project not. Or wonder from were some classes come or have troubles when accidentally shadowing a definition. In general I personally would prefer a bit of boilerplate for more clarity in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest not to do that because we can import each class specifically in scala. You should make use of that advantage. I had answered a similar question long back. Importing a particular class makes it light weight. That way you are importing only the packages you are using. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59148346/12197961 If you are looking to just optimize your code and reduce the number of lines in your code you can probably do this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5745305/12197961